# Why does context not have the activity's primary color attribute?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm writing a library that has an activity for photo editing. When the user is done editing, there is a "done" button with a color background. I want to be able to customize the color of the button so I have static methods in a *different class* that create drawables with different colors. Something that I want to do in this class is a function that receives a `Context` reference and creates a drawable with the primary color. Here's my code:

```
//code from FlatButtonDrawable class companion object
fun new(ctx: Context): StateListDrawable{

            val typedValue = TypedValue();

            val a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, intArrayOf(R.attr.colorPrimary))
            val color = a.getColor(0, 0);

            a.recycle();
            return createColorDrawable(color)
        }
```

This function gets the primary color from the `Context` and returns a drawable with that color. The problem is that the primaryColor attribute is not found, so it returns a colorless drawable.

What's even weirder is that if instead I fetch the primary color in my activity and *then* call the static method, it works. Here's the code:

```
//code from activity class
val sendButton = findViewById(R.id.sendPhoto) as Button
val typedValue = TypedValue();
val a = obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, intArrayOf(R.attr.colorPrimary))
val color = a.getColor(0,0)
a.recycle()
sendButton.background =FlatButtonDrawable.createColorDrawable(color)
```

So the real question is: **Why does `obtainStyledAttributes` fail when called from my static method using the activity's context reference, but it succeeds when called from the activity?**

Comment: I don't see that your StateListDrawable uses `Activity` as `Context`. Could you provide code of calling this function?